# 7 unclaimed devices in lshw output

Tags: drivers, devices

I have seen some similar questions to this but I have never seen one with as many unclaimed devices in the lshw output, I am wondering if this is normal. I know that unclaimed means that there is no driver associated with the device, but I can not interpret what these devices are. I have an HP ENVY 13.

```
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
--
              *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: HP USB-C HDMI 2.0 Adapter
                   vendor: Hewlett-Packard
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 0.15
                   serial: 101
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:3
--
              *-usb:4 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   vendor: Synaptics, Inc.
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 0.00
                   serial: c2e7b4c62b26
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:5
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
--
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
--
                    *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                         description: Windows FAT volume
                         vendor: mkfs.fat
                         physical id: 1
                         version: FAT32
                         serial: c0d9-497b
                         size: 495MiB
                         capacity: 497MiB
                         capabilities: boot fat initialized
                         configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
                    *-volume:1
--
        *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
--
  *-power UNCLAIMED
       description: OEM Define 1
       product: OEM Define 5
       vendor: OEM Define 2
       physical id: 2
       version: OEM Define 6
       serial: OEM Define 3
       capacity: 75mWh
```

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; nor any clues as to what system you're using (was it a *headless* intended product you're trying to install on a laptop or device it wasn't designed for), & stack details (LTS releases offer two stacks; HWE for newer hardware).   You've not eliminated the user-error situations with your post (ie. trying to use an older software expecting it to know about more modern hardware that wasn't released/created at the time software was developed/released) with your question as whilst you gave device; you didn't provide any details as to your software stack...